# Class Not Registered - AxMicrosoft.Office.Interop.OutlookViewCtl.AxViewCtl

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook

I am trying to upgrade an old application. To reduce the complexity I have currently upgraded the application to Dotnet V2.0. The application has an outlook module which uses the 'AxViewCtl'. I am unable to load this control while running, but in the design view I am able to see the outlook mails getting populated.

Each time I run the application I am getting the following error.

> Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Stack trace:

```
    at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithoutLicense(Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String license, Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit()
   at App.frmOutlook.InitializeComponent() in d:\App\Forms\frmOutlook.cs:line     212
   at raft.raftlegal.frmOutlook..ctor() in d:\App\Forms\frmOutlook.cs:line 37
   at raft.raftlegal.RaftLegal.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\App\Main.cs:line 3231
```

When googled with above details, I got to know that there is a problem with DLL. I registered all the relevant DLLs still I am getting the same error always. request you to assist me in solving this issue. Please comment incase you need more details, will be providing ASAP.

Comment: If it works in design-view then the most likely problem is that your app runs in 64-bit mode.  It won't in design-view, VS is a 32-bit process.  Right-click your EXE project > Properties > Build tab > Platform target = x86.

Comment: @HansPassant tried that too, but the error exists.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered very same situation with Visio control. The project was created with Visio 32 bit on one 32 bit computer and then run with Visio 32 bit on another 64 bit computer. Because the project was built as "Any CPU", it started as 64 bit process on 64 bit machine and was not able to load 32 bit Visio. At the same time, Visual Studio was installed as 32 bit and was able to load 32 bit Visio control into design environment very fine.

After I changed project target to x86 explicitly, everything fixed. If I had Office 64 bit version installed, I would have to change build target to x64 to succeed. If the above advise to change platform target did not work for you, please double check again to ensure that bit mask of your MS Office installed coincides with bit mask of your project target. If you make right selection, I m sure that it should fix.

Be aware of it also when deploying your solution to your clients: you should maintain two versions: x86 and x64 for any project, which uses MS Office ActiveX components. Users should explicitly select the right version of your application corresponding to their installed version of MS Office in order that it work correctly.

I believe that comment by @HansPassant is exactly correct answer to this question. All credits should be given to him.